# Rename Portions of Strings in List While Keeping Index

Tags: c#, string, list, rename

I'm looking for help strategically renaming alphanumeric strings in a list while keeping their indexes.

I maintain several parallel lists to the missionList mentioned in the code below so the indexes are important.  The problem arises when a user removes one of the entries in the list that will leave a gap between mission types of the same name.

> Removing Mapping2 from {Mapping1, Mapping2, Mapping3}
>   leaves {Mapping1, Mapping3} but I would like it to be {Mapping1,
>   Mapping2}.

This is not difficult until other mission types are added, like Erosion and Crime.  There is an undetermined amount mission types so the code needs to be prepared for this.

> A renaming operation of {Mapping1, Mapping3, Erosion2} should result
>   in {Mapping1, Mapping2, Erosion1}.

I've added code below that sets up for this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> missionList = new List<string> { "Mapping1", "Mapping3", "Erosion2",
            "Mapping4", "Erosion3", "Crime1", "Mapping6", "Mapping8", "Erosion1" };

        for (int i = 0; i < missionList.Count; i++)
        {
            // Get the mission number
            int firstNumber = missionList[i].IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(missionList[i].Substring(firstNumber));

            // Get the mission name
            string name = missionList[i].Substring(0, firstNumber);

            //TODO: Rename missionList strings
            //      - Index of each string remains the same
            //      - Each "name" portion of the string stays the same
            //      - The "number" portion of the string is changed to reflect its position 
            //          in relation to items with the same "name"
            //          ex. { "Mapping4", "Mapping3" } becomes { "Mapping1", "Mapping2" }
        }

        /*  After remaming, missionList should be:
            { "Mapping1", "Mapping2", "Erosion1", "Mapping3", "Erosion2", "Crime1", 
                "Mapping4", "Mapping5", "Erosion3" }   */
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a list of strings isn't the best data structure for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

    private static void DoIt()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("\\d*", RegexOptions.None);//we'll use this ro remove the existing numbers
        List<string> thelista = new List<string>() { "aa11", "ab2", "aa4", "df4" };//lets fake a list
        List<string> thelist = new List<string>() { "Mapping1", "Mapping3", "Erosion2", "Mapping4", "Erosion3", "Crime1", "Mapping6", "Mapping8", "Erosion1"};//Lets fake your list

        List<string> templist = new List<string>();//our temp storage
        Dictionary<string, int> counter = new Dictionary<string, int>();//our counting mechanism


        for (int i = 0; i < thelist.Count; i++)//loop through the original list of string
        {
            templist.Add(regex.Replace(thelist[i], ""));//strip the number and add it to the temp list

            if (!counter.ContainsKey(templist.Last()))
            {
                counter.Add(templist.Last(), 0);//add the type to the counter dictionnary and set the "counter" to 0
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < templist.Count; i++)//loop through the temp list
        {
            counter[templist[i]]++;//increment the counter of the proper type
            templist[i] = templist[i] + counter[templist[i]];//add the counter value to the string in the list
        }

        thelist = templist;//tadam

    }
```

Input

```
Mapping1
Mapping3
Erosion2
Mapping4
Erosion3
Crime1
Mapping6
Mapping8
Erosion1
```

Output

```
Mapping1
Mapping2
Erosion1
Mapping3
Erosion2
Crime1
Mapping4
Mapping5
Erosion3
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!